# Bad layout in users page (new)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

A part from the really small font size (discussed **[here](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/some-font-sizes-are-too-small)**), which is a new "feature" after **[this bugfix](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/bad-layout-in-users-page)**, now the first two columns have tags misaligned with the last two columns.

See below the alignment of <sub>natural-remedies</sub> with <sup>aviation</sup>.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure 100% why this is happening. There are 2 classes of user icons, one that is more "MVP" as I was told. and then a regular user. However in your view it seems to be all MVP level users that feature the drop shadow, so I don't know what's causing the space issue yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conflict with mod-flair diamond (thanks @balpha) and this is fixed on dev. Will push w next build.